# Can you specify which version of docker-compose-plugin to install?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/

```
VERSION_STRING=5:18.09.0~3-0~debian-stretch
sudo apt-get install docker-ce=$VERSION_STRING docker-ce-cli=$VERSION_STRING containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
```

According to the article, we can specify which version of docker-ce and docker-ce-cli we can install by using the VERSION string. What about the docker-compose-plugin? I want to keep docker at a specific version along with docker compose. Would the above command install the latest docker compose everytime I run it? I want to freeze both docker and docker compose versions.

Answer (score 0):

To freeze versions - mark a package as held back, which will prevent the package from being automatically installed, upgraded or removed:

```
$ sudo apt-mark hold package-name
```

Comment: That's not my goal. My goal is that on every server, I have the same package version. If I build one today and next week a newer version comes, I want to install the older version. I can specify the version numbers for docker-ce and docker-ce-cli but not for docker-compose-plugin

Comment: Then get the version with `apt madison` command and then install it. After that - you can freeze

Comment: I think `docker-compose-plugin` is not a separate package. So cannot install a specific version.